# Is loss or accuracy a more appropriate measure of performance for a classifier?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a model which has a lower loss value than the baseline model I'm comparing to, but also slightly lower accuracy. The model was trained to classify time series into one of two classes. In general, which is a better indicator of performance and why? I have seen conflicting answers on this and I'm still confused.

Comment: If your loss is a proper scoring rule then the loss is a better measure of performance than accuracy since accuracy can be optimized by very poor models (e.g. guessing most prevalent class)

Comment: Please don't just repost [the same question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/520233/1352). Instead, edit the original question to clarify.